# Non Numeric features in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, categorical-encoding

I understand that the fitted values for Logistic Regression can be expressed as:

$$P(Y_i=1) = \left(1+\exp(-\hat{\theta}^TX_i)\right)^{-1}$$

where $X_i$ is the feature vector, which will work well when the features take only numeric values.

However, when the features are non-numerical, can we use the same approach as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512863/linear-regression-substituting-the-non-numerical-discrete-domain-of-a-predictor) for a Linear Regression model?
Or is there a better way which we can use for Logistic Regression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coding of regressors are done exactly the same way in logistic regression as in linear regression. And, by the way, the same way in Poisson regression---all of the GLM's (generalized linear models).  In fact, for a lot of other kind of models too.  There may be some other considerations in addition, but the same principles apply.